# Efficiently determine if a number out of a range of subsequent numbers is in an ordered list. (in Python)

Tags: python, list

We have an ordered list of numbers. Now we want to check if a member of a range of numbers is inside the list.

Something like `range(5, 10) in mylist`
If either 5,6,7,8 or 9 are in mylist it should return the element that is first found in the list, else Null, or False.

For Example, if mylist would be something like `[1,2,3,7,8,10,15]` the function would return 7. If the list would be `[1,2,3,4,12,13]` the function would return None/False.

Now think big lists and big ranges, and the operation gets unperformant. How can I implement this so it has a better performance?

Comment: Are the lists sorted?

Comment: Yes, we want to search in sorted lists.

Comment: Binary search for the start of the range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [binary-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) twice, for each boundry of your range (using [`bisect.bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)).

If the indexes returned are the same, there is no intersection (return `None`).

If they are not, return the element at `start_index` (where `start_index` is the index you got for your range's `start`).

Here's the code:

```
import bisect
def intersect_range(lst, start, stop):
     start_i = bisect.bisect_left(lst, start)
     stop_i = bisect.bisect_left(lst, stop)
     if start_i == stop_i:
         return None
     else:
         return lst[start_i]

intersect_range([1,2,3,7,8,10,15], 5, 10)
=> 7
intersect_range([1,2,3,7,8,10,15], 5, 6)
=> None
intersect_range([1,2,3,7,8,10,15], 15,30)
=> 15
intersect_range([1,2,3,7,8,10,15], 0,1) # "stop" is excluded from range
=> None
```

Since you perform two binary-searches, the complexity is O(logN), where N is the length of your list.

---

EDIT:

there is also a slightly faster alternative, which is to binary-search range's start, and then check if `lst[start_index]` is in the range (`start <= lst[start_i] < stop`). This reduces the number of `logN` operations from two to one. The code looks like this:

```
def intersect_range(lst, start, stop):
    start_i = bisect.bisect_left(lst, start)
    if start <= lst[start_i] < stop:
        return lst[start_i]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I think you'd want `bisect_left` rather than `bisect`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what we were looking for, this just boosted the performance of our program to the stars.

Comment: Do you need to binary search twice? You only need to binary search for the start of the range, this would be able to give you the found element even if it didn't match, and then you would just see if this was in the range. Wouldn't this work?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I beat you to it by seconds! :)